# Prevent a case-when-expression to change the result type

Tags: sql, mysql, jdbc, types, case

I'm processing the results of a select statement in Java using JDBC. In the select statement I have the following expression where `x` is a column:

```sql
case when <some-condition> then x else null end
```

I expected the result of this expression to have the same type as `x`, but at least for the type `BOOLEAN` this is not the case.

The type of a `BOOLEAN` column is reported as `BIT` and it has values of `true`, `false`, or `null`.

But the type of the case-expression with `x` being a `BOOLEAN` is `TINYINT` and it has values `1`, `0`, or `null`

### Question

Is there a way to construct the expression above so that the result will have the same type as the column `x`?

Bonus points when the construct is standard SQL and works on a wide array of databases.

### Reproducer

I use the following Java code to play around with the problem:

```java
JdbcTemplate jdbc = ...;

jdbc.execute("""
        create table demo(
          test_bool boolean
          );
        """);
jdbc.execute("""
        insert into demo values (true);
        """);
jdbc.execute("""
        insert into demo values (false);
        """);

RowCallbackHandler typePrinter = rs -> {
    int columnType = rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(1);
    System.out.println(rs.getObject(1 ) + "\t" + columnType + "\t" + JDBCType.valueOf(columnType));
};

jdbc.query("select test_bool from demo", typePrinter);
jdbc.query("select case when test_bool then test_bool else null end from demo", typePrinter);
jdbc.query("select case when test_bool then null else test_bool end from demo", typePrinter);
```

The output of it is:

```
true    -7  BIT
false   -7  BIT
1   -6  TINYINT
null    -6  TINYINT
null    -6  TINYINT
0   -6  TINYINT
```

Comment: BOOLEAN isn't a real type in MySQL. It's an alias for `TINYINT(1)`

Comment: I have seen that statement before. But the code I included demonstrates that the column straight out of a table has a different type then the `case` expression, whatever these types are named inside MySql. I don't really care what types they are, as long as they are the same.

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html) says: **BOOL, BOOLEAN

These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true:**

Comment: Hmm, so the case expression doesn't change the type, but the precision? Which then turns into different JDBC types ...

Thanks, that leads to a better understanding, if not a solution to the problem.

Comment: There's a general problem when you have different datatypes in different `WHEN` and `ELSE` clauses. It has to find a common type for all of them.

Comment: If you want to force it to return BOOLEAN, try using `CAST(CASE ... END AS BOOLEAN)`

Comment: When constructing the SQL I don't have information about the database type. I need something that works for all types. Updated the question to make that explicit.

Comment: I don't think there's any control over how MySQL determines the combined type of `CASE`. Maybe report this as a bug, since `NULL` shouldn't change the type.

Comment: if you're working with expressions which case when is, you cannot get the original type of a column, and you shouldn't care about it, just handle it as the type mysql reports